# Вывести адрес переменной в Си без `printf`

Tags: c, указатели

Допустим у меня есть переменная, я записываю ее адрес в указатель.
Как мне без `printf` вывести адрес указателя и адрес переменной которая хранится в указателе?

Comment: Получите адрес, это просто число - ну а уж число-то вывести сможете? Надеюсь, `putc` разрешена?

Comment: Используйте преобразование указателя в число: `(unsigned)pointer` и `(unsigned)(&pointer)`.

Comment: @Гоша Соминский  Как вы собираетесь без функции вывода что-то вывести?

Comment: Вывести куда? В файл?На экран?

Comment: @bsuart, а какая разница куда?

Comment: Перевести число в строку и вывести любой другой функцией.

Comment: @PinkTux, считаете нет разницы?)

Comment: Обьясню более подробнее..
В данный момент я пытаюсь сделать функцию идентичную функции `printf`, по идее я могу принять указатель через библиотеку `stdarg`, но что делать дальше я пока не понимаю, так как это не просто число это 16 - ричное число, а значит в простую переменную (я пробовал) засунуть не удастся. Куда именно выводить в файл или на экран я разницы не вижу, тут главное понять как его обработать и превратить в стринг для вывода. `putc` свой все что я могу использовать для вывода это `write` библиотека `unistd`

Comment: @bsuart, объясните в чём по-вашему разница между выводом в файл или на экран (контрольный вопрос: что такое таблица дескрипторов файлов и что там по умолчанию записано в первых трёх элементах?)

Comment: @PinkTux, так мне нечего переводить. Да в указателе записан адрес, но как мне до него добраться?

Comment: @PinkTux, объясню свое видение: я вижу задачу:вывести адрес переменной в СИ без printf. Куда по условию мне ее выводить, чтобы решить данную задачу?Контрольный вопрос-)))

Comment: Ой, судя по вашему более подробному объяснению, проблема у вас не в том, чтоб без `printf` что-то сделать. Простите, но, по-моему, у вас какая-то каша получилась. Почему 16-ричное число нельзя засунуть в переменную? Какая разница, како представление у числа? :)

Comment: @PinkTux, первые три дескриптора забиты по умолчанию тремя файлами, один на клаву второй на экран и третий для ошибки, std -in -out -err
В чем разница между выводом на экран и в файл помнится смутно.

Comment: @bsuart, *" Куда по условию мне ее выводить, чтобы решить данную задачу"* -- очевидно, в `stdout` или `stderr` (или в `fileno(stdout)` / `fileno(stderr)` / `STDOUT_FILENO` / `STDERR_FILENO`)

Comment: http://we.easyelectronics.ru/blog/Soft/2400.html - здесь собрано немало способов перевести число в строку.

Comment: @PinkTux, очень полезная статья, спасибо:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В комментарий не втиснусь, так что в ответе... См. тут - http://ideone.com/jVhnOs

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int a;
    printf("%p\n",&a);
    intptr_t p = (intptr_t)&a;
    char s[2*sizeof(p)];
    for(int i = 2*sizeof(p)-1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
       s[i] = "0123456789ABCDEF"[p & 0x0F];
        p >>= 4;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 2*sizeof(p); ++i)
    {
        putc(s[i],stdout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Гуд, плюс!!! (и еще 4символа нужно для коммента)

Comment: А 64 бита пробовали?

Comment: @0andriy А поменять `unsigned int` на `intptr_t` самостоятельно слабо?